# Change of base proof without reciprocal

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I am looking for a proof of the change of base formula without using the reciprocal.

I know that: $$log_ax=\frac{log_bx}{log_ba}$$

The proof usually involves taking the reciprocal: $log_ax=y$ therefore $x=a^y$

**Question:** How to prove without using the reciprocal? So I want my proof to look like this: $$log_ax=...=...=...=\frac{log_bx}{log_ba}$$

Comment: Why do you want a proof with this retriction? The $log$ function is defined in this way, i.e.:$$\log_ax=y\iff x=a^y$$

Comment: What about $$\log_bx = \log_b (a^{\log_a x}) = \log_ax \log_ba$$?

Comment: @Crostul I would like to start with log_a...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just multiply with $\log_b(a)\over \log_b(a)$:

$$\log_a(x) = {\log_a(x)\log_b(a)\over \log_b(a)} = {\log_b(a^{\log_a(x)})\over \log_b(a)} = {\log_b(x) \over \log_b(a)} $$

Comment: I don't understand your third step...

Comment: @ImreVégh third step is because $a\ln x=\ln x^a$

Comment: I mean the step before that...

Comment: Which step? $a^{log_a(x)} = x$?

Comment: Using $a^{\log_a(x)} = x$ is exactly the same as using $x=a^y=a^{\log_a{x}}$

Answer (score 1):

By definition
$$x=b^{\log_bx}$$
Taking the logarithm in base $a$
$$\log_ax=\log_a(b^{\log_bx})=\log_bx\log_ab$$

For $x=a$, we have $1=\log_ba\log_ab$; therefore
$$\log_ax=\frac{\log_bx}{\log_ba}$$

It's just a bit more complicated than the direct way.

By definition
$$
x=a^{\log_ax}
$$
and, taking the logarithm in base $b$
$$
\log_bx=\log_b(a^{\log_ax})=\log_ax\log_ba
$$
so
$$\log_ax=\frac{\log_bx}{\log_ba}$$